# Replace XML Path Stuff Query

Tags: sql, t-sql, for-xml-path, stuff

I would like to replace the following query as I have performance problems. The execution plan is giving me a lot of redisual due to Table Spool operators (Lazy Spool)

```
SELECT DISTINCT LOT_0, 
VarCode = STUFF(
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + IT6.ID_0
    FROM  TOLOT S
        INNER JOIN  ETMM I ON I.ITMREF_0=S.ITMREF_0
        INNER JOIN  SICOD6 IT6 ON IT6.ID_0=I.TSICOD_6
    WHERE IT6.LNGDES_0 <>'' AND LOT_0 <> '' AND TSICOD_0 = 'OP'
    AND S.LOT_0=S2.LOT_0
    FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value ('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, ''
    ),
VarShort = STUFF(
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + IT6.SHODES_0
    FROM  TOLOT S
        INNER JOIN  ETMM I ON I.ITMREF_0=S.ITMREF_0
        INNER JOIN  SICOD6 IT6 ON IT6.ID_0=I.TSICOD_6
    WHERE IT6.LNGDES_0 <>'' AND LOT_0 <> '' AND TSICOD_0 = 'OP'
    AND S.LOT_0=S2.LOT_0
    FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value ('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, ''
    )
,VarLong = STUFF(
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + IT6.LNGDES_0
    FROM  TOLOT S
        INNER JOIN  ETMM I ON I.ITMREF_0=S.ITMREF_0
        INNER JOIN  SICOD6 IT6 ON IT6.ID_0=I.TSICOD_6
    WHERE IT6.LNGDES_0 <>'' AND LOT_0 <> '' AND TSICOD_0 = 'OP'
        AND S.LOT_0=S2.LOT_0
    FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value ('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, ''
    )
FROM  TOLOT AS S2
GROUP BY LOT_0
```

I would appreciate your ideas

Comment: Assuming you're on a recent (supported) version of SQL Server then use `STRING_AGG`.

Comment: If not, I didn't but you need those `DISTINCT`s in there; I suspect you have a problem with your joins (either the explicit or lateral).

Comment: Your outer query has a `DISTINCT` and a `GROUP BY` too; a sure sign of a problem. Your data will already be in distinct sets, so the `DISTINCT` is either redundant (and just results in performance degradation) or your `GROUP BY` is wrong. I would suggest the former.

Comment: What version (`select @@version`) of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @Larnu I will be making the changes and I will come back with the result.

Comment: @Stu Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU24) (KB5001228) - 14.0.3391.2 (X64)

Comment: Then you're in luck, SQL Server 2017 supports `String_Agg()`, it is much more performant than using `for xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are on SQL Server 2017, you can simply use `STRING_AGG`

```sql
SELECT
  S.LOT_0, 
  VarCode  = STRING_AGG(IT6.ID_0, ', '),
  VarShort = STRING_AGG(IT6.SHODES_0, ', '),
  VarLong  = STRING_AGG(IT6.LNGDES_0, ', ')
FROM TOLOT AS S
LEFT JOIN ETMM I
    (INNER JOIN SICOD6 IT6 ON IT6.ID_0 = I.TSICOD_6)
  ON I.ITMREF_0 = S.ITMREF_0
  AND IT6.LNGDES_0 <> '' AND TSICOD_0 = 'OP'
WHERE S.LOT_0 <> ''
GROUP BY
  S.LOT_0;
```

Comment: The difference in performance is abysmal but I don't get the same values. Old:              
NULL NULL NULL |
GEN01 Generic Generic  |
FUG03 FuggleUK Fuggle, United Kingdom |
FUG03 FuggleUK Fuggle, United Kingdom |
CTZ01 CTZ CTZ

Comment: New:    (There are no more nulls)                                                                                                                             
GEN01 Generic Generic |
FUG03,FUG03 FuggleUK,FuggleUK   Fuggle, United Kingdom,Fuggle, United Kingdom |
CTZ01,CTZ01,CTZ01 CTZ,CTZ,CTZ CTZ,CTZ,CTZ |

Comment: You can try left-joining instead, have edited